# What is the variable to allow alterations to be made to tumblr's new /image/ page?

Tags: tumblr

I cannot seem to find any instruction on how to go about making changes to the seemingly new '.../image/...' page on the [tumblr guide](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes) (under 'Basic Variables')

When making changes to the '.../post/...' page for example, I can use '{block:PermalinkPage} {/block:PermalinkPage}'

Does anyone know the variable to allow changes to be made to the '.../image/...' page?

Comment: At this point in time we aren't able to make changes to that page. I assume they'll eventually provide some variables for it, but at this point we just have to live with it.

Comment: You could override all links (preventDefault) to '/image/' and using the corresponding image URL, open it in a custom modal window (or whatever you want to do)

Answer (score 0):

Changes can't be made to that; the purpose of the page seems to be to provide a nicer-looking version of just linking to the image itself, which, of course, is inherently not customizable either.

You can prevent linking to the `/image/` page by using `<a href="{Permalink}">` or `<a href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}">` instead of `{LinkOpenTag}` and `</a>` instead of `{LinkCloseTag}`. But this has a side effect of removing support of click-through links.